# jquery simplemodal close wont work in firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.simplemodal 1.3.5 (i tried older versions)
the close button doesnt close the modal in firefox (i tried IE and it work fine)
this is the test page i am using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style>
    #simplemodal-overlay {
   background-color:#000;
   cursor:wait;
 }
 #simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
  background: url(../images/modal_close.png) no-repeat;
  width:25px;
  height:29px;
  display:inline;
  z-index:3200;
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  right:18px;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 .modala
 {
  width: 372px;
  height: 206px;
  background: url(../images/modal.png) no-repeat;
 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 test page
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery.simplemodal-1.3.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $("body").click(function() { $.modal("<div class=\"modala\"><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>", {overlayClose: true} ); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

what can be the problem? is it a known problem with simplemodal and FF?

Answer (score 0):

simplemodal is a deprecated library. You better use something like http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Comment: [Simplemodal is a plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/), not a library. It's still being maintained and developed.